# How to make a div the lenth of the page

Tags: html, css

How would i go about making the div i am using to contain the page stretch all the way to the bottom of the page.

You can see that here: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats The white div don't go all the way to the bottom of the page this is making it ugly.

Whats the best way to go about making this always stretch to the bottom of the page relative to the browser size?

Thanks.

If you need any code of the website to help me do this please ask.

**EDIT** Right all i really want is that white bar to stay static over the background and then let the products scroll over the white box so its always in the center of the page how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the *top bar* outside of the *whitebg* as it might make this easier.

Set your **body**:

```
padding: 0;
```

Set your **.whitebg**:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -625px;
top: 0;
padding-top: 60;
height: 100%;
```

You'll probably notice how you have a scroll bar on the right even when it isn't necessary. I think moving the top bar out of the whitebg will remove your need for the padding-top: 60 which should help get rid of the scroll.

** **EDIT** **

If you move the top nav bar outside of whitebg I think it works well leaving a lot of your css as-is.

**.whitebg**

```
position: absoulte;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -625px;
top: 50px;
padding: 10;
height: 100%;
```

** **EDIT #2** **

The key here is to get your background to encompass the area you desire. Then user other inner elements to handle positioning of the contents within. If you try to add a margin or padding onto the outer most background element, you'll find that it will exceed the desired size since those will always **add on** to the height or width.

**.holder**

```
remove the padding-top
```

**.whitebg**

```
remove all padding
```

**.bodycon**

```
add margin-top: 50px;
change margin-bottom to a normal margin
```

**.fotter**

```
add a margin if desired
```

Comment: Ive got the main page looking great: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats&id=12

Thats exactly how i wanted it but now when i go onto the catagorys page the white isnt touching the bottom how would i make it so it goes all the way to the bottom without making it not fit properly on the working page.

http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats

I need the white div to always meet the bottom of the page if there is content there or not. How would i do this thanks.

Comment: Part of your problem is the combining of padding with a height of 100%. The padding will add onto that height. In there I see you have added a div with a "holder" class. It has a 100% height, and a 50px top padding. This top padding is what is causing you to have extra white on the bottom in addition to the scroll bar.  I will edit the above again with some follow changes you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `height: 100%` on .`whitebg` selector

Comment: Tried this and its left a gap at the bottom: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats&id=18

Answer (score 0):

Just inspected your page..try to set the `bottom: 0px;` to your `whitebg` class

```
.whitebg {
    ..your existing code..
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First ill ask why you have all  meta tags in body?:)
If the blue bar is fixed position you can try

```
html, body{
height:100%
}
.whitediv{
height:100%;
}
```

Or just doo simple jquery:

```
var docheight = $(document).height();
$('.whitediv').height(docheight);
```

And make it as function on window.resize

Answer (score 0):

This Code should help you,

```
.WhiteBag{
height : 100Vh;
}
```

Ask if you have any doubt

Comment: `Vh` is about the height of the viewport, which is the visible part of the _page_  but not the height of the complete _page_

Comment: I just thought what would be apt for the problem of the author...
well in that case i thing @ivan answer would be perfect....

Answer (score 0):

Add these in style

```
.whitebf
{
height:800px;
width:100%;

}
```

this one in your footer

```
footer
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;

}
```